# Increasing security on imageUpload, issues with img src="image.php"

Tags: php

Cant seem to get the php script to execute and fetch the image script, the image placeholder.jpg is sored outside of the public_html webroot, here is what i do

Show image .php file

```
<img src="image.php?image=<?php echo urlencode('placeholder.jpg') ?>"/>
```

image.php

```
<?php

    $file = basename(urldecode($_GET['image']));
    $fileDir = '/noaccess/avatars/';

    if (file_exists($fileDir . $file))
    {
        $contents = file_get_contents($fileDir . $file);

        header('Content-type: image/jpg');

        echo $contents;
    }

?>
```

Comment: A warning to readers: this code is using `file_get_contents()` and will accept any arbitrary file path (including a relative file path). File_get_contents [accepts relative paths and will happily open your raw PHP scripts](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php#84956). A script like this would let a hacker download any file on your server your PHP script has read access to, including your PHP source files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is EXTREMELY unsecured to run that kind of script, because you are giving hackers access to your file system remember they can use `../` to navigate up the folders,
but anyway try this:

```
<?php

    $file = basename(urldecode($_GET['image']));
    $fileDir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'noaccess/avatars/';

    if (file_exists($fileDir . $file))
    {
        $imageRes = imagecreatefromjpeg($fileDir . $file);
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        // Output the image
        @imagepng($imageRes);
        // Free up memory
        @imagedestroy($imageRes);
        die();
    }

?>
```

Comment: I was told that this aproach was safer, making it harder to execute the file, if they upload something malicious

Comment: Not really, someone could theoretically access any file only from the `/noaccess/avatars/` dir

Comment: @OneTrickPony Couldn't they access `/noaccess/avatars/../../fileOutsideThoseFolders.txt`?

Comment: The advantage with my solution is that if the file they try to access is not an image, imagecreatefromstring will fail and return false, and nothing will be done.\

Comment: @OneTrickPony Signs point to `file_get_contents()` accepts relative paths just fine.

Comment: @John That may be the case (I don't know), but that's a separate issue. You're accepting any arbitrary filepath, then getting and returning its contents. Normally a user can't access those files via your webserver, but your PHP script with its file system access will happily open _any_ file and upload it to the hacker. They can't execute files on your machine, but you would be uploading your configuration files, for instance, or your PHP code, or that file with the database username and password in it.

Comment: hey you're right, seems to work with file_get_contents. Didn't expect that from PHP :)

Comment: @OneTrickPony From a comment on the [file_get_contents() doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php): _"if $filename has a relative path file_get_contents returns the uninterpreted sourcecode of the php-file with all comments etc."_

Comment: So can you suggest a better alternative for handeling user fileupload ?

Comment: Try the example above, like I said it is un-hackable.

Comment: I just figure out I used imagecreatefromstring instead of imagecreatefromjpeg :p, but it is fixed now.

Comment: @Hermann "Un-hackable" - those are strong words! The docs don't appear to state under what conditions imagecreatefromjpeg actually succeeds or fails, so there are possibly circumstances it will open, say, a PHP file (the image won't display correctly, but maybe the binary will still contain the text of a PHP file).

Comment: The issue still remains, cannot seem to get the image.php to run from html, as in src="image.php?image=<?php echo urlencode('placeholder.jpg') ?>"

Comment: and isnt the header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); supposed to be outside of the IF statement ? :)

Comment: I suspect '/' for you mean the root of your app not the computer root, I added the remaining part of the path to the root of the computer.

Comment: Fixed it, works now, had an issue with the home dir, and it didnt echo test strings due to it needed an img served, my bad, very new to test, but thanks a bunch!

Comment: i also added $file = str_replace("../", "", $file);  just in case